# Connect Configuration page not showing

Tags: docusignapi

We have been having issues in seeing connect configuration in docusign production account. We see the red color message

> "Oops! We had trouble loading your Connect configurations. Go ahead and try that again"

But i can see the same page from classic preferences, no issues there.
Any idea why this is happening in the new docusign connect page?

[image]

Comment: Can you please post a screen shot and URL of the page where you are receiving this error.

Comment: i added screen shot link

Comment: What is the URL?

Comment: I suggest logging out and then logging back in. I've seen this same sort of problem. I believe that you were automatically logged out but the admin tool didn't realize that was the issue.

Comment: @rajen let us know if logging out and logging back resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was a temporary glitch that got resolved later. The issue was fixed.